# Programmatically retrieve version history changes of an Sharepoint list item

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint CSOM (C#), how do I retrieve the item version history for a particular version? For example, for an item there are 8 major version.
I need to retrieve programmatically 2nd version from the changes history.

[Please refer below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I49P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [CSOM Version September-2017](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-september-2017/), you can also access the field values of previous versions. The blog conatins a simple code sample.

Answer (score 0):

CSOM doesn't provide API to  get version history of a list item. You will need to use SharePoint web service to retrieve the version history and related data of list item In client-side. The code for this can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/177ceafb-debd-4020-b943-904c220cbf5f/how-to-get-list-item-versions-using-csom?forum=appsforsharepoint).

Comment: in this way we need to pass feild name each time. but i need to get all the changes happened for that particular version. Can you please suggest?